# How to overlap navigation bar

Tags: ios, view, navigation, push, spaces

Anyone had this problem before ?
I  had set my navigation bar to be transparent .When i push to a new view controller the view does not overlap the navigation bar . It leaves a white spaces which i don't want to . I want the uiview to be full to the top of the screen rather than below the navigation bar because i want it to be transparent so that it show the transparent navigation bar with image view  .

Here some example

https://www.dropbox.com/s/teuhsdt6u4agr6e/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-25%20at%205.21.14%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you set the navigation bar as transparent by setting the `translucent` property to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation bar is not there on the image you put as example. It looks like an image view positioned an appropriate amount of space below the top.

Navigation bar will always be visible if there is one. If you don't want the navigation bar to be displayed, present the view controller instead of pushing it onto the navigation stack.

Comment: sry i had made my navigation bar transparent so it wont show i want the result to be like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/wd8uv1ev9pp8rml/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-25%20at%205.38.50%20PM.png?dl=0